# how should a group of input (with an Unknown number) be posted?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a regular form to be POSTed.
However some input tags are generated dynamically.

For example;

There are tables with 2 column but the number of row is depends on users. These rows have input tags. So I dont think its wise to give names in every input tag.

Briefly;

```
<form method="POST" action="foo.php">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>   <td> <input> </td><td> <input> </td>   </tr>
   <tr>   <td> <input> </td><td> <input> </td>   </tr>
   <tr>   <td> <input> </td><td> <input> </td>   </tr>
   ...
   ..
   .
  </tbody>
 </table>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How can these inputs can be read under foo.php (as a group).

If all these inputs have same name. Will they be under same name? (assuming all their name is "name1"). after POST operation will they be constructed as an array like

```
$_POST['name1'][0] 
$_POST['name1'][1] 
$_POST['name1'][2] 
$_POST['name1'][3]
```

Or every input value will be over written by the next one ?

Shortly; how should a group of input (with an Unknown number) be pos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post more then one input with the same name, the name has to be `name1[]`. Then `$_POST['name1']` will be an array in PHP.

Comment: Do you mean 10 input element like this <input name="name1[]"> willcreate a $_POST['name1']array[0to9] ??

Comment: Yes, then `count($_POST['name1']) === 10` meaning you'll have 10 items in that array